# OMNeT++ IEEE 802.1Q priorities

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to make a network with a switch that supports Ieee802.1q tagging. I checked the examples in inet but they were only helpful in regards to making VLANs which I now understand. My question is if the standard switch created in inet supports priority queueing with the Ieee8021qHeader and, if so, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct support for priority queueing based on that field, but could be done relatively easily:

Check the `inet.queueing` package. There is a whole lot of queuing, scheduling etc. related stuff there.  (you can check the tutorial too: https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/queueing/doc/index.html)

What you need is to deploy `inet.queueing.PacketQueue` (see docs in the NED file) (or `DropTailQueue` (if you have to limit the queue size) which is just a PacketQueue with a drop strategy configured)

Implement an `IPacketComparatorFunction` class in C++ to order your packets as you need and then configure that class as the `comparatorClass` parameter of the `PacketQueue`.

The `EtherMac` is currently configured to use `EtherQueue` as a queue module, which is a `DropTailQueue` parametrized with a comparator that gives priority to ethernet PAUSE frames using `inet::EthernetFrameComparator` (see that for an example, how to create a comparator class).

Once you implement proper comparator based on VLAN tags, you can just configure your own comparator as the queue's `comparatorClass` parameter.